# Combine a List from one model into another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two different models. One is a viewmodel the other is standard model. I am trying to combine the results from one model into the second viewmodel. I am stuck on the looping part.

```
var model = new SurveyPageViewModel()
            {
                SurveyId = surveyData.Id,
                Title = surveyData.Title,
                Id = surveyData.Pages[0].Id,
                Questions = new List<QuestionViewModel>()
                {
                    new QuestionViewModel()
                    {
                        // I want to use the data I pulled in my surveyData here.
                    }
                }
            };
```

Models:

```
public class SurveyPageViewModel
    {
        public int? SurveyId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
    }

 public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        public string SubType { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
```

My Other model:

```
public class SurveyPageViewModel
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }

            public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
        }

 public class Question
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string QuestionType { get; set; }

        public string SubType { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        public List<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need something like `Select`

```
Questions = surveyData.Questions.Select(q => new QuestionViewModel
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        QuestionType = q.QuestionType,
        ...
        Options = Options
    }).ToList()
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` for this. Also you might consider tools like Automapper if such mapping task is frequent for you.